# Regex matching blank, any char and/or newline for given sequence

Tags: java, regex

I have three different possible scenarios to match with a regex explained below.

First the file inputs that I need to match:

-- 1 --- (anything in between On and :

```
 On whatever:
```

-- 2 -- (On adjacent to :)

```
 On:
```

-- 3 -- (any char between the On and :)

```
 On=:
```

-- 4 -- (an = and /n between the O and :)

```
 On=
 :
```

This is the regex that I'm trying to match but no luck

```
// String text = <file contents from above>
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(On\\s(.+):)$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOITALL);
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("Not sure if this is correct to get all 4cases to step in here???");
}
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but I'm pretty sure you're overthinking this. All of these scenarios can basically be simplified to: anything between On and :, including newlines or an empty string. So from what I can tell, `On.*:` should do the trick.

Comment: You are right...I was very much overthinking things to say the least. The (.*) worked just fine for all cases include the /n (case 4).  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this.

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(?:On:|On\s?([^:]*):)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

or maybe

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(?:On:|On\s?([\S\s]*?):)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Answer (score 1):

By `^(On\\s(.+):)$` you are saying: "from the beginning of the line, I want to match 'On' followed by *exactly one* space, followed by *at least* one character of any kind, followed by a colon, and then the end of the line".

With this regexp, you would match the first case `"(.+)" ==> 'whatever'`; however, the second case would **not** match (the expression will fail because it is expecting one space after "On" and then at least another character before the colon; the third case wouldn't match either because it is missing a space; finally, the fourth case would match alright.

So, as Toni answered, `^On.*:$` would do the trick. However, I guess you are trying to group whatever comes after the "On" part, so I guess you could use `^(On\\s*(\\S*)\\s*:)$`, which is the same as saying "match 'On' followed by any sequence of whitespaces, followed by a token comprehended by any sequence of non-whitespace chars, followed by another sequence of whitespaces and then the colon. This will also give you two groups: the first one will contain "On *whatever* :"; the second one will contain the *whatever* part alone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Great breakdown and summary!

Answer (score 1):

What about the next? It's more simple.

```
On([^:]*):
```

e.g.;

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("On([^:]*):");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "On=\n:";

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).matches()
    );  // prints "true"

    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
"=\n"
```